# Whats the correct Xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

```html
<span class="jsx-2465661648"><span class="jsx-2748387826 new-tag">Neu</span>Brunel GmbH NL Bielefeld</span>
<span class="jsx-2465661648">Arvato Supply Chain Solutions</span>
```

The output should be the strings:
"Brunel GmbH NL Bielefeld"
"Arvato Supply Chain Solutions"

When i use //span[@class="jsx-2465661648"] i get NEUBrunel GmbH NL Bielefeld which i dont want.
How can i extract the text without the new tag "Neu"?

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath-1.0 expression. It only selects the direct text children.

```
//span[@class='jsx-2465661648']/text()
```